# Error opening the OrientDB database

Tags: java, orientdb, tinkerpop

I have a problem with the URL where I am trying to catch my DB. 
Here is the code:

```
TransactionalGraph graph = new OrientGraph("/home/danicroque/Escritorio/demoCroque", "admin", "admin");
```

Here is the error:

```
run:
may 20, 2016 2:49:46 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFORMACIÓN: OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=907MB (heap=846MB os=3.802MB disk=447.700MB)
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on opening database '/home/danicroque/Escritorio/demoCroque'
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:204)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:168)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.openOrCreate(OrientBaseGraph.java:1818)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.<init>(OrientBaseGraph.java:161)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.<init>(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:102)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.<init>(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:98)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph.<init>(OrientGraph.java:103)
    at pruebatodook.PruebaTodoOk.run(PruebaTodoOk.java:23)
    at pruebatodook.PruebaTodoOk.main(PruebaTodoOk.java:16)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error in database URL: the engine was not specified. Syntax is: <engine>:<db-type>:<db-name>[?<db-param>=<db-value>[&]]*. URL was: /home/danicroque/Escritorio/demoCroque
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.loadStorage(Orient.java:441)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:187)
    ... 8 more
may 20, 2016 2:49:46 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFORMACIÓN: OrientDB Engine shutdown complete
/home/danicroque/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I am trying to run this code in Ubuntu with Netbeans. The name of the DB is `demoCroque` and the URL is `/home/Escritorio/demoCroque`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your URL is formed incorrectly.

See here: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Console-Command-Connect.html

```
<database-url> Defines the URL of the database you want to connect to.
It uses the format <mode>:<path>

<mode> Defines the mode you want to use in connecting to the database.
It can be PLOCAL or REMOTE.

<path> Defines the path to the database.
```

Try something like this as your URL:

```
REMOTE:192.168.1.1/demoCroque
```

Or

```
PLOCAL:../home/Escritorio/demoCroque
```

Edit: for the purpose of testing use a full file path until you know it works correctly, for example:

```
PLOCAL:C:/projects/myproject/Escritorio/demoCroque
```